# JavaScript Object Orientation Storing Multiple Items and Properties and Display

Tags: javascript, html

Would you be able to help me, I have been using a book and they have shown me a way to create an object in JavaScript and I have used there method but I am having trouble displaying it. My aim is to display it in a table using HTML 5 and I am going to create 9 more items to call upon and display. The book tells me to use product1.ShowDetails to display it but I have tried but having issues

Thank you for your time,

James

```
<script>
function Item(product, description, stockLevel, price)
{
    this.Product = product
    this.Description = description
    this.Stock_Level = stockLevel
    this.Price = price
    this.showHeading = function()
{
    document.write(this.product )
    document.write(this.description)
    document.write(this.stockLevel)
    document.write(this.price)
}
this.showDetails = function()
{
    document.write(this.product)
    document.write(this.description)
    document.write(this.stockLevel)
    document.write(this.price)
}
product1 = new Item("Shorts (F)", "Stone Wash Dmin Shorts", 20, 25.90);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript properties are case sensitive. In your constructor you set `this.Product` to the `product` parameter but the `showDetails()` function references the `this.product` parameter.

Also, your code seems to have a typo, should the last bracket not be before product1 is declared?